# Getting Row's Name in a DataList

Tags: asp.net, templates, header, datalist

I have a datalist and would like to pull the row names from the table that I am getting my values from for the datalist.  Heres an example of what I would like to do.

```
<HeaderTemplate>
    'Get data row names
'Maybe something like Container.DataItem(row)?
    </HeaderTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a DataTable as a Data Source for your Data List you could use the `OnItemCreated` method and provide a custom handler for the `ItemCreated` event to add the column header values. I'm not sure why you would want to do this. It sounds like a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) or [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) might be better suited to your needs. At any rate, here's the code.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemCreated="DataList1_ItemCreated"
            ShowHeader="true" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT [id], [name], [email], [street], [city] FROM [employee_tbl]", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        DataList1.DataSource = dt;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }

  protected void DataList1_ItemCreated(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                Literal lit = new Literal();
                lit.Text = col.ColumnName;
                e.Item.Controls.Add(lit);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, but I doubt it would work.  I don't believe DataItems are available at the point when the Header is being created.

```
((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).DataView.Table.Columns
```

If this works, you can loop through this collection and inspect each item's ColumnName property.

A better idea would be to either:

1. Create a property in codebehind that returns a `List<string>` of appropriate column headers.  You can refer to this property in markup when you're declaring the header.
2. Add a handler for the ItemDataBound event and trap header creation.  You will still need a way to refer to the data elements, which probably haven't been prepped at this point.